# About Hom(V,V) and group

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, education

I was looking an example to show this The set of all non zero elements of Hom(V,V) is not a group under the composition of linear operators.

Comment: I tried a lot but was unable to find such an example. Tell me about the example and i will try to prove the rest.

Comment: Find a non-invertible element, like $(x,y)\mapsto(x,0)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself.

Comment: Please provide a little more detail

Comment: As I dont understand that how can i take this since we are in Hon(V,V) and its elements are only operators

Comment: The easiest thing is the zero operator, which maps everything to zero.

Comment: Is zero operator a non zero element of Hom(V,V) ? And if yes then which property of group fails to hold so that it doesn't form a group

Comment: If $V$ is $1$-dimensional, then $\text{Hom}(V,V)\setminus\{0\}$ is a group.  Otherwise, $\text{Hom}(V,V)\setminus\{0\}$ is not a group.  For $\dim(V)>1$,  $\text{Hom}(V,V)\setminus\{0\}$ is not even closed under composition.

Comment: Man this is the thing i have to prove but how to prove this i dont have any idea please add some details

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having trouble coming up with specific examples. A linear operator is an operator $A$ such that
$$A(ax+by)=aA(x)+bA(y)$$
For example, on $\mathbb R^2$ the function 
$$A(x,y) = (x,0)$$ 
is a linear operator (a nonzero element of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$), as is
$$B(x,y)=(0,y)$$
But
$$AB(x,y)=(0,0)$$
for all $(x,y)$, so the set of nonzero elements of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ is not closed under composition, since $A\neq 0$, $B\neq 0$, but $AB=0$.

You could also show that $A$ is not invertible and that would disprove that the set is a group as well.

It's worth saying that if $V$ is one-dimensional then the set of nonzero elements of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ actually is a group, but it is not a group provided $\dim(V)>1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help man.